# Yodlee - getMFAResponse isMessageAvailable true but no questions returned

Tags: yodlee

Following https://developer.yodlee.com/Instant_Account_Verification_API/IAV_Services_Guide/IAV_API_Flow/IAV_Matching_Services_API_Flow for account verification, I'm reaching a scenario where after a putMFARequest post is sent with the MFA challenge response, the follow-on getMFAResponse returns a message similar to this one:

```
{"isMessageAvailable":true,"fieldInfo":{"questionAndAnswerValues":[],"numOfMandatoryQuestions":-1,"mfaFieldInfoType":"SECURITY_QUESTION"},"timeOutTime":119220,"itemId":10105282,"errorCode":0,"retry":false}
```

Based on the sample application code I've reviewed and the API docs, this seems to infer that I should be presenting my user a MFA form but there is no data to render the form.  In this scenario, since the errorCode is 0, is it safe to ignore the isMessageAvailable value and proceed forward or is there something else I need to do in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as you have received errorCode - 0 you should proceed forward.